# Date and time on one line

Tags: punctuation, time, dates

**How does one display a date *and* a time on one line?**

Example:

```
Sep 25, 2019
20:59
```

How would this be displayed on one line? Adding another `,` after `2019` does not look/feel right to me. Is there a rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write either

> Sep 25, 2019 at 20:59

or

> 20:59 on Sep 25, 2019

---

For the British date style there is no comma needed to separate

> 25 Sep 2019 at 20:59

or

> 20:59 on 25 Sep 2019

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) combined date and time representation:

"2019-09-25T20:59"

How to format dates and times is a style question that depends on what your audience expects and understands.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I am interested in a format that's optimised for parsing by a human.